# Running 2 methods with X amount of time difference?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a mic, which I want to activate for 5 seconds and then get that data. While the activity thread is still running.

Method 1: Is the activation of mic.

Method 2: Is for collecting the .amr/.mp3 output from the file.

And this will only happen one time.

I want that my activity should call method 1 at the start and after time X(or 5 seconds), it should call the other method. I am able to do this manually by using 2 buttons, one for record and other for save  the file. But I am unable to do this automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
firstMethodCall();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    secondMethodCall();
}
}, 5000);
```

Or better:

```
firstMethodCall();
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
@Override
public void run() {
    secondMethodCall();       
}
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Nope, I have explicitly mentioned only 2 times. Not after every 5 seconds.

Comment: you mentioned 2 method calls, second should be called 5 seconds after first one, and you havent mentioned how many times this has to occur

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is only 2 times. Man.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Solution should suffice then. After calling your first method, you should start the TimerTask, which should contain the second method call within its run().

Comment: I have edited to make it more clear. I hope this is what you were talking about @TobiasHvassMølbak

Comment: Looks good! Based on @Saleh_Ninja question, that is the way I would do it.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek and Tobias.

Comment: @Saleh_Ninja please accept the answer if you like it. this motivates us

Comment: I have upvoted But can't accept the answer as my reputation is lower than 15.

Comment: ahh that!! no prob, glad i was of help

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Thread.
2. Call first method, Thread.sleep() for some time
3. and Then Call Second Method.

Example:

```
    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            firstMethod();
            Thread.sleep(time);
            secondMethod();
        }
    };

    //on button click
    thread.start();
```